# Java end point crashes

Tags: java, android, api

I am making an Android application and I am trying to use an API to get meal recipes. I have a `RequestManager` class which handles the API calls. Unfortunately, it skips the `OnResponse` and `OnFailure` methods and does not work even though I have checked the `query` it is sending , and it is okay.

`RequestManager` class

```
public class RequestManager {
    Context context;
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.spoonacular.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    public RequestManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void getRandomRecipes(RandomRecipeResponseListener listener)
    {
        CallRandomRecipes callRandomRecipes = retrofit.create(CallRandomRecipes.class);
        Call<RandomRecipeApiResponse> call = callRandomRecipes.callRandomRecipe("10", context.getString(R.string.api_key));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RandomRecipeApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RandomRecipeApiResponse> call, Response<RandomRecipeApiResponse> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    listener.didError(response.message());
                    return;
                }
                listener.didFetch(response.body(), response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RandomRecipeApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                listener.didError(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private interface CallRandomRecipes {
        @GET("recipes/random")
        Call<RandomRecipeApiResponse> callRandomRecipe(
                @Query("number") String number,
                @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);

    }
}
```

After debugging it, I saw that every time after coming on `call.enqueue(new Callback<RandomRecipeApiResponse>()` it just jumps to the very end and that is it.

Does anyone see a problem here?